# delete or erase a portion of an opened file with python

Tags: python, file

is anyone could help me in finding a function that deletes just a portion from an opened file starting from its beginning. In other words, the program will open a file and read for example the first 100 bytes. Is there a built-in function on python or a way that helps me deleting just those first 100 bytes before closing the file (the file will be shifted to the right by 100 bytes). (FYI: truncate() does not help since it deletes the contents of a file starting from the current cursor position, I would like exactly the inverse-delete the content from beginning till the current cursor position and leave the rest.). Thank you

Comment: You're unlikely to find a good general answer to this question because it has more to do with the operating system and less to do with Python, and on most systems, files are stored as a linear sequence of bytes and cannot efficiently be "shifted right" the way you describe. Typically the answer will involve creating a new file from the remaining bytes in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want to do *efficiently* for large files, or just something you want to do in general?

It's pretty easy to do by reading in the file, and then writing it out:

```
import os
dat = open(filename, 'rb').read()
open(filename+'_temp', 'wb').write( dat[100:] )
os.rename(filename+'_temp',filename)
```

Note that this operates "safely" by first creating the new file, then moving it into place. If there is a failure anywhere, the old file will not be clobbered.